# Window Function Over clause

Tags: google-bigquery

In the Over Clause documentation mentions  "Rows", and "Range"..

```
OVER (
      [PARTITION BY <expr>]
      [ORDER BY <expr>]
      [ROWS <expr> | RANGE <expr>]
     )
```

However, I couldn't find any detailed explanation regarding their functionality or any samples for their use. Can someone please explain what are they and how can they be used?

Comment: It's like any T-SQL rows/range in OVER, you find plenty of examples on Google. Like: http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/rows-and-range-preceding-and-following/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See user 'sprocket' answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27574474:

ROWS and RANGE allow the window function to look at a user defined window of rows, for example the previous 27 to run a moving average:

```
SELECT spend,
       SUM(spend) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 27 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
       user,
       date
FROM user_spend;
```