# Running Sum of Last 30 days by day

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for a query that sums all the leads from the last 30 days (including that day) by each day.

For example...

if date=8/1/18 then I want a sum of the leads from  7/2/18 to 8/1/18
if date=3/17/20 then I want a sum of the leads from  2/17/20 to 3/17/20

[Here is a link to a sheet where the concept is layed out](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kwe7CFbUV6P3Byt4xQg23-DF1FLJS94mA7aYUQuuArY/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Your answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557919/bigquery-sql-for-28-day-sliding-window-aggregate-without-writing-28-lines-of-sq

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  SUM(leads) OVER(last_30_days) AS running_sum
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW last_30_days AS (
  ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
```