# BigQuery: Computing aggregate over window of time for each person

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, google-bigquery, window-functions

Given a table in Google BigQuery:

```
User  Timestamp 
A     TIMESTAMP(12/05/2015 12:05:01.8023)
B     TIMESTAMP(9/29/2015 12:15:01.0323)
B     TIMESTAMP(9/29/2015 13:05:01.0233)
A     TIMESTAMP(9/29/2015 14:05:01.0432)
C     TIMESTAMP(8/15/2015 5:05:01.0000)
B     TIMESTAMP(9/29/2015 14:06:01.0233)
A     TIMESTAMP(9/29/2015 14:06:01.0432)
```

Is there a simple way to compute:

```
User  Maximum_Number_of_Events_this_User_Had_in_One_Hour  
A     2
B     3
C     1
```

where the time window of one hour is a parameter?

I tried doing this myself using a combination of LAG and partition functions by building off of these two questions:

[BigQuery SQL for 28-day sliding window aggregate (without writing 28 lines of SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557919/bigquery-sql-for-28-day-sliding-window-aggregate-without-writing-28-lines-of-sq)

[Bigquery SQL for sliding window aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415647/bigquery-sql-for-sliding-window-aggregate)

But find those posts are too dissimilar since I am not finding number of people per time window, but instead finding max number of events per person within a time window.

Comment: btw: expected value '3' for User B is wrong - should be 2! as distance between 1:05, 1:06 and 12:15 is far above 1 hour. unless there are locality  involved somehow

Comment: Thank you! Fixed the example :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an efficient succinct way to do it that exploits the ordered structure of timestamps.

```
SELECT
  user,
  MAX(per_hour) AS max_event_per_hour
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    user,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY timestamp RANGE BETWEEN 60 * 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as per_hour,
    timestamp
  FROM 
    [dataset_example_in_question_user_timestamps]
)
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: great use of RANGE. you still need to get MAX though. And one more  - timestamp in your example table is sting so you need to cast it to timestamp and then to sec or msec for above to work. Still really very nice!

Answer (score 2):

Try below for GBQ. Haven't tested much, but looks workable to me

```
SELECT
  User, Max(events) as Max_Events
FROM (
  SELECT 
    b.User as User, 
    b.Timestamp as Timestamp,
    COUNT(1) as Events
  FROM [your_dataset.your_table] as b
  JOIN (
    SELECT User, Timestamp 
    FROM [your_dataset.your_table]
    ) as w 
  ON w.User = b.User
  WHERE ROUND((TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(w.Timestamp)) - 
               TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(b.Timestamp))) / 3600, 1) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but I came up with a better one so I'm going to post that. I'll let you look at though before I accept my own answer - see what you think!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a query like this (In T-SQL):

```
SELECT "User", SUM(s) As Maximum_Number_of_Events_this_User_Had_in_One_Hour  
FROM (
    SELECT "User", 1 s
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY "User", CAST("Timestamp" As date), DATEPART(Hour, "Timestamp")) As t
GROUP BY "User"
```

Comment: He mentioned he uses Google BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but I came up with a better one so I'm going to post that. I'll let you look at though before I accept my own answer - see what you think!